# Post redirect to 404 page from admin side in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I faced a strange issue in my blog. when i publish new articles from admin almost 75% of time it redirect to www.maydomain.com/wp-admin/post.php (Page not found) and nothing saving on the DB.I checked the wordpress forum for this issue they mentioned few things like

```
1) Disable all the plugins
2) Adding htaccess section 
# BEGIN 404 Fix

<IfModule mod_env.c>
#SetEnv MODSEC_ENABLE Off
#PassEnv MODSEC_ENABLE
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

#END 404 Fix
```

3) Increase the memory limits and maximum size on wp-setting.php

All this i have done but the problem remains. Another strange thing i found is this will happen only on server my localhost xampp its working fine.On server sometime its works fine wordpress version is 3.5.2 and plugin are used only recaptcha and seo yoast

I am using meetgaverwp frame work and theme is there any fix for this problem ?
The whole day i stuck with this ! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue.
The issue with old post update or adding new.
First of all I figure out why its happen .The post contain some php variables like session_start() , $_SERVER[] etc is blocked by server.
In some host it will works by disabling mod_security in htacces file.
But on shared host its not works that is why its happen to my blog.

The Solution is Just ask for Hosting Provider and ask to fix with disabling mod_security for your account. The issue fixed Works like charm .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Now that you did the fix, you probably need to login using a different browser. Redirects are cached for a while.

If your new browser works, clear the cache in your main browser and try again.

Comment: No hope, I tried with clearing the cache.any alternate solution?